# std::bad_weak_ptr while shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

To create my EventManager, I needed to create functions which would take shared_ptr of Listeners to store them into vectors and call their event function.
I did so, and it works correctly, unless when I close my program.

When closing it, the program crashes, saying "double free or corruption". I understood my problem came from my std::shared_ptr(this). So I tried to use shared_from_this... but it doesn't really seem to work.

main.cpp :

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "EventManager.h"

int main() {
    EventManager evManager;
    std::shared_ptr<Game> game(new Game(&evManager));
    return 0;
}
```

Game.h & Game.cpp :

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "EventManager.h"
#include <memory>

class EventManager;
class Game : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Game>
{
    public:
        Game(EventManager* evManager);
};
#endif // GAME_H
```

---

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game(EventManager* evManager) {
    evManager->addGame(shared_from_this());
}
```

EventManager.h & EventManager.cpp

```
#ifndef EVENTMANAGER_H
#define EVENTMANAGER_H

#include <memory>
#include "Game.h"

class Game;
class EventManager
{
    public:
        void addGame(std::shared_ptr<Game> game);
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<Game> m_game;
};

#endif // EVENTMANAGER_H
```

---

```
#include "EventManager.h"

void EventManager::addGame(std::shared_ptr<Game> game) {
    m_game = game;
}
```

I executed my program with hope it would work, but I got a std::bad_weak_ptr. This error seems to occur when you try to create a shared_ptr from something that no longer exists.

So I thought it could be that the program ended too fast for the shared_ptr to create. Unfortunately it's not the problem, I added a std::cout after the creation of the Game class and it never shows, the program crashes before.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me solve it,
Cheers.

Comment: Does your presentation really require five files and main? Couldn't you have condensed it to a representative example that's more compact?

Comment: It may be that the internal weak pointer is not updated until after the object has been created, so you cannot use `shared_from_this` in the constructor.

Comment: Your implementation of the `Game` constructor calls `shared_from_this` *before* any shared pointer to that object exists -- that's not allowed.  That is, you can only invoke `shared_from_this` when a shared pointer to `this` already exists.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you, it works when I make it outside the constructor.

Comment: And sorry for the code in many files, I tried to make it all in one file but failed :c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this

> Notes
>
> It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (until C++17)std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a default-constructed weak_this) (since C++17).

you call `shared_from_this` in constructor when there's no shared_ptr yet